# How to create popup for email link with major email provider links?

Tags: views, ajax, javascript

Check out this new feature craigslist implemented. WHen you click on this button (like in the link below) that says "reply to this post", it pops up with this popup that shows the different email providers options (for web browsers, and local clients like Outlook).

[image: screenshot]

How can this be done for Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [take a look here](http://drupalsn.com/learn-drupal/drupal-tutorials/great-jquery-plugins-drupal). Lots of JQuery plugins that integrate with Drupal.

I think [Lightbox](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) best fit here but check the rest. It provides a pop-up overlay similar to Craigslist's

I myself don't have any experience with these but since no one has answered thought I could try point you somewhere useful.

I did a quick search and also found these that could lead somewhere:

```
http://www.lullabot.com/articles/announcing-beautytips-jquery-tooltip-plugin
http://www.jquerypopup.com/
```

Anyway, I hope those hints helps you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Please look in to this, it explains the same https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/2286